# Jquery Tags Plugin Paste Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery Tag Plugin by [XOXCO](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) . It works great but when some one does paste text which has comma it doesnt seperate them out . I tried this solution . **https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/issues/22** . But it appends new pasted tags twice . Has anyone used this plugin and came across same issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on their code at github, you could try this as a workaround:

```
$('#input').on('paste',function() {
    $(this).trigger('keypress');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An other simple solution is

```
$('#tags').tagsInput({
    'onAddTag': function(tag) {
        //Remove all newlines
        tag = tag.replace(/\n/g, '');
        //Remove all spaces
        tag = tag.replace(/\s/g, '');
        //check if a comma is find inside var tag
        if (tag.indexOf(',') > 0) {
            $('#tags').importTags(tag);
        };
    }
});
```

And voila !

Answer (score 0):

this supports pasting a comma separated string

```
onAddTag: function(tag) {
    var tags = tag.split(",");
    if(tags.length > 1) {
        $(this).removeTag(tag);
        return false;
    }
  }
```

looks a bit wierd, but the tag lib already treats commas as separator, so the remove simply refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of Pit Digger's initial problem with the double tags.
`$(e.target).val()` already has the added tags. Adding `+ ',' + e.tags` will just double the tags. In my solution I commented out the the old version and added the new line above.

Original code: https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/issues/22

```
var tidyTags = function(e) {
    var tags = ($(e.target).val()).split(',');
    //var tags = ($(e.target).val() + ',' + e.tags).split(',');
    var target = $(e.target);
    target.importTags('');
    for (var i = 0, z = tags.length; i<z; i++) {
        var tag = $.trim(tags[i]);
        if (!target.tagExist(tag)) {
            target.addTag(tag);
        }
    }
    $('#' + target[0].id + '_tag').trigger('focus');
};
```